# json.net serilalization char and deserialize unexpected value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

i use newtonsoft dll for serialize object to MySql Db.

When i serialize a char use:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, typeof(char))
```

then when i access to object i use:

```
var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(json);
```

Now the type of value is String.

I Expected that the type will be **char and not string.**

If i serialize any other type like int, string, uint, bool, enum etc' and use DeserializeObject with generic Object i get the real type.

So, There is way to serialize Char and when Deserialize with generic Object i get char and not string?

Thank!

Comment: There's no `char` data-type in JSON, so a char is serialized to a string of length 1. When deserializing, you will need to specify the type.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have been working with Newtonsoft's JSON library over two years now and when serializing an object I never defined the second parameter and I did not have any problems so far.

You need to deserialize your Json object by defining the target type. So if you expect it to be a char at the end your code should be as following;

```
var value = //somwthing
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, typeof(char));
value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<char>(json);
```